# mootools click event not working in iphone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, mootools, mootools-events

I'm using very simple markup `button` and attaching a click on it via mootools (latest 1.6):

```
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
<script>
    window.addEvent('domready',function(){
        document.id('btn').addEvent('click',function(){
            //...do something
        });
     });
</script>
```

this code works everywhere except when i try to run it over iphone 6(i guess all mobile ios).

tried also to register `touchstart` event via mootools - with no luck.
Anyone can point me to my mistake ? is it a mootools issue or ios issue ?

Comment: could be a bug in DOMREADY as the dom should already be released by then. click code has not changed. touch events are now native.

Comment: Have you tried it with the `type="button"` attribute on the button tag?